# laravel 8 high memory usage

Tags: php, laravel, memory-management, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8 for my project. When I installed laravel-debugbar to monitor my app's performance I realized that my memory usage is 21mb. first I thought the high memory usage is because of my codes but when I created a fresh laravel 8 project I still got high memory usage - about 17mb using debugbar.
since some people said that the debugbar adds extra memory usage itself,I also used a code to determine memory usage.
I added code below at the end of index.php in public folder. I found this code from someone's github reposittory:

```
    echo convert(memory_get_usage());

function convert($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}
```

with the code I get 13.14mb. still very high. don't you think this is high for a fresh project?

Comment: I think you have a very strange understanding about what is a "high memory usage".

Comment: wordpress starts to work at 64mb :)

Comment: if you're worried about memory usage (e.g. you plan to install this on a device with very limited memory) then maybe switch to a micro-framework like e.g. lumen but note you will be giving up on a lot of features

Comment: That is on the high side. Because I just created a fresh Laravel 8 project and the first load took about 6MB but all subsequent loads were at 4MB.

Comment: thank you guys for your guidance. I am going to use this project on a shared hosting and the memory usage limit is up to 128mb. So I was thinking with laravel 8 I will reach to max if 10 users are online at the same time